# Migrating a Mariadb/wordpress site with only .frm files

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mariadb

My server crashed. My /home /www and lib/mysql were on a different hard disk so I have all the data. The original server was Debian 9 with Mariadb and an apache webserver. I planned to move to mysql so I have a debian 10 server with mysql. I also have another debian 9 server with Mariadb so that I can use sqldump to move my databases. All my databases moved over fine, except one that was a wordpress database. That directory only has .frm files in it, there are no .MYD or .MYI files. I tried copying them to /var/lib/mysql of the Deb9 server, changed the permissions and ownership. However, mysql dump gives the following error message

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1932: "Table 'dbname.tablename' doesn't exist in engine" when using LOCK enter code here
```

I tried copying them as is to the MYSQL server too, the server did not see the tables. In the MariaDB server command line interface it shows the tables. However when I try to view the contents of any table it says

```
Error 1932 (42S02): Table 'dbname.tablename' doesn't exist in engine
```

I get the same error when I try repair table.

Any ideas on how I can get this moved?

Comment: don't fiddle with mysql files individually. Use the entire datadirectory only. What mysql/mariab version are you using. Could it be the dbname.tablename is not myisam but innodb? This question will move to dba.stackexchange.com/ , SO is just for programing.

Comment: Apologies for the wrong forum for the question. How do I move it? I do have the entire directory, which only has the .frm files and the db.opt file.  I actually have the entire /var/lib/mysql from the original server. All the other databases have .MYD and .MYI files except this wordpress one. The mariadb version I am using is  10.1.44. I don't remember what I was using on the original server but that was deployed 2 years ago and regularly updated.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved my issue. Instead of copying only the database folder, I copied the entire /var/lib/mysql folder to the mariadb install. Then I did sqldump on each database and moved them to the mysql server. I'm not sure why the copy of the database folder didn't work but I got all my data back.

Comment: the database folder mechanism doesn't work for innodb because a number of critical aspects aren't in the database folder, they are in the top level folder.  Using SQL like you have done is the recommended way of migrating between different database implementations. In place (same dataadir) upgrades can be attempted going up 1 major version, but otherwise, back to SQL like you've done.